# Is Clustering for Influxdb available on Windows

Tags: influxdb

I have managed to build influxdb from source for windows, without much issue.
I am now trying to get their clustering to work as per:
https://influxdb.com/docs/v0.9/guides/clustering.html

That assumes a linux os.

When updating the influxdb.conf from localhost to the RealHostName in step 2 and starting the first node

The logs return:

```
2016/01/06 15:01:44 Go version go1.5.2, GOMAXPROCS set to 8
2016/01/06 15:01:44 Using configuration at: influxdb.conf
[metastore] 2016/01/06 15:01:44 Using data dir: D:\XXXXXX\.influxdb\meta
[metastore] 2016/01/06 15:01:44 Skipping cluster join: already member of cluster
: nodeId=1 raftEnabled=true peers=[localhost:8088 RealHostName:8088]
[metastore] 2016/01/06 15:01:44 Node at RealHostName:8088 [Follower]
[metastore] 2016/01/06 15:01:45 Node at RealHostName:8088 [Leader]. peers=[localhost
:8088 RealHostName:8088]
[metastore] 2016/01/06 15:01:45 Node at RealHostName:8088 [Follower]. peers=[localhost:8088 RealHostName:8088]
```

Is there some I am missing? or is this part of their disclaimer:

> Clustering is in a alpha state right now. There are still a good
>   number of rough edges. If you notice any issues please report them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clustering in InfluxDB 0.9 should be considered alpha functionality, and Windows is not yet a supported OS for InfluxDB. Since you are using alpha functionality on an unsupported OS it may be impossible to fix whatever issues are happening.

I recommend waiting for the 0.10 release later this month, which will have clustering in a beta/RC state. Full Windows support is coming soon but I do not have an estimate yet.

You might also consider running your cluster Linux server. Are you completely locked into deploying InfluxDB on Windows?

Comment: Yeah, I know I am pushing the line of how and where I can use influx, but unfortunately the choice of OS is out of my control, due to corporate policies and processes. With our current monitoring requirements I probably don't need a cluster at the moment it was more an investigation for future requirements.

Comment: Makes sense, Brian, thanks for the context. We absolutely will support clusters on Windows, but that may not be for many months. (There are some Windows-specific compilation challenges we won't address until the code settles a bit following the query engine and storage engine rewrites, both of which should resolve by end of February.)